# Grabbing text of a single element in XDocument (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document that looks like

```
<a>foo<b>bar</b></a>
```

Creating an XDocument with the above XML, then using

```
doc.Descendants(new XName("a")).First().Value
```

results in "foobar" rather than "foo" as I expected.

How can I just get the value of `<a />` without subtracting the value of `<b />` from `<a />`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a>` actually contains two nodes, a text node and the `b` element. You can filter `a` children to of type `XText`:

```
var xml = "<a>foo<b>bar</b></a>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(document.Descendants("a").First().Nodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem kind of invalid XML. Maybe you should try attribute ... something like this

```
<a name="foo">
<b>bar</b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite an answer, but I would question the validity of your XML in this example.
Consider the XML-compatible markup for a HTML paragraph with a hyperlink:

```
<p>Go to the <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a> front page</p>
```

The contents of the paragraph (the value of `<p>` ) is still the full sentence rather than just the words "go to the ".

Also, given your example, what happens if you have more text *after* `<b>bar</b>`?